# SnapRoads - how to?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

I've implemented a Google Location Api on my app to track my routes. I record my coordinates in a sqlite Db and then save these coordinates as a GPX file to see on map parsing and build via polylines.
There are a lot of points.

I see that unfortunately the position not seems follows the road even if I drive/walk in the middle of it.
Searching with google I've founded SnapToRoads as part of Google map API but, unfortunately not for Android, even if it seems that is possible to implements (but I don't know in which manner).
I wonder if someone knows how to solve this problem or some workarounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I implemented SnapToRoad API to solve this problem, even if I have to use my key on source code (if I don't want implement a web site with Javascript)